# Anatta & reincarnation

Tags: anatman, tibetan-buddhism, reincarnation, soul

**Buddhism**

1. *Anatta* (no-self doctrine)
2. Reincarnation (death-rebirth cycle in *samsara*)

How can something that *doesn't exist* reincarnate?

Answer (score 2):

In very simple terms, "Anatta" implies that a self does not exist. It does not imply that nothing exists.
'Re-incarnation' is a continuing process. The phenomena that appear as a self is what continues.

Comment: If there's no self (*anatta*), what is it that reincarnates?